# adding and removing from the page in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am using flash for the first time, I have a set of videos and image galleries, for users who are viewing it, I have created an Exit button so that the users can come out and go back to the menu. How do I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Ok, in Flash CC, I have an image gallery, and a video gallery. When it is preloaded into the main.fla I want users during playback or viewing to exit and go back into the main area/menu. I have created an Exit button but it does not have functionality. For the button, what code do I use in AS3?

Answer (score 0):

Ok that you are looking for must be :

```
buttonExit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removePlayer);

function removePlayer( evt: MouseEvent ):void{

  stage.removeChild(myVideoPlayer);

}
```

Is that what you need?

Comment: Looks about right, and what modification would I use if I had an image gallery array? same thing but just with different ID isn't it?
Thanks Buddy

Comment: I guess to do with images you would need to define an ID for each image container and when you would click on "Exit" button for this image, you would have something like : function removeImage( evt: MouseEvent ):void{

  stage.removeChild(theImageID); //Where 'theImageID' is the name of the image container

}

Comment: By image container do you mean an image array?

Comment: Hmmm I imagine a structure like : Stage > Gallery (Main container) > Image sin their own container (Movieclip or Sprite) > Bitmap. With a loop on an array you create 1 container by image and each container have a "close" button. On click on close button, you 'removeChild' the target bitmap container (the parent's bitmap). But I don't really know how is build your project so I just guess something like that.

Comment: Thanks bud, I'll give that a try

Comment: I suddendly remember another trick. If you include the "close" button INSIDE the image container, so you will have a structure : Gallery > Image container ('Close' button + bitmap), you can use something like function removeImage( evt: MouseEvent ):void{

  var child:DisplayObject = evt.currentTarget as DisplayObject;
  var parent:DisplayObjectContainer = child.parent;

  gallery.removeChild(parent); //The parent is the main container

}

Comment: That way, you don't even need to play with IDs